# Is there a more concise way to write this in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

This subroutine is passed an array of file handles to close, which it closes one by one using the `foreach` loop:

```
sub closef
{
    foreach(@_) {
        my $fh = shift;
        close $fh;
    }   
}
```

Where all can this simple subroutine be modified to make it better?

Should I use `close shift` instead of doing it in two lines?

Comment: That won't do what you think it does. You can't be shift()ing the thing you're foreaching. Behavior is unpredictable.

Comment: I second @tchrist's basic message. If you want to use shift, `while ( @_ )` is a better match for a loop. If you're going to `foreach`, then just `close $_`. Or, see @David Dorward's second example of how to combine the `foreach` with the variable assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach(@_) {
    close $_;
}
```

or

```
foreach my $fh (@_) {
    close $fh;
}
```

or

```
close $_ foreach (@_);
```

Answer (score 12):

The most concise way is to use lexical filehandles which automatically close when they go out of scope:

```
sub firstline {
    open( my $in, shift ) && return scalar <$in>;
    # no close() required
}
```

See perldoc [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Indirect-Filehandles).

Comment: +1 for using lexical filehandles and letting them close themselves when their scope exits.

Comment: Thanks @eugene, I did not know about these, will continue to explore.

Answer (score 8):

```
sub closef { close $_ for @_ }
```

But the `close` function does have a return value and you would usually do well to examine it. Therefore,

```
sub closef { map { close $_ } @_ }
```

Comment: If you do check the value, you may also want/need to examine `$!` variable, so whilc this is a great improvement as far as error handling, this is not 100% sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't doing what you think. You say you want to close each filehandle passed to the routine, but you only close some of them. Consider the following example:

```
sub t{
        foreach(@_){
                my $tmp = shift;
                print $tmp;
        }
}

t(('a'...'d'));
```

This will output

```
ab
```

Despite the argument list being a, b, c and d. This is because on each iteration shift is being called. To get the kind of behavior you want use

```
sub t{
        foreach(@_){
                my $tmp = $_;
                print $tmp;
        }
}

t(('a'...'d'));
```

Or, better, don't make a copy of $_, just alias it:

```
sub t{
        foreach my $tmp (@_){
                print $tmp;
        }
}

t(('a'...'d'));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for these examples. I had no idea this was happening.

Answer (score 4):

There's an issue with the subroutine originally posted.

The [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) function expects an array as an argument. The implicit variable inside the `foreach` is a scalar.

This means that `$fh` remains uninitialized. The reason why it probably goes unnoticed is because ([as eugene y points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050080/is-there-a-more-concise-way-to-write-this-in-perl/4050140#4050140)) lexical filehandles close themselves when they go out of scope.

Incidentally, `use warnings;` will notify about such things.

A more idiomatic approach would be to use a `while` loop:

```
sub closef {

    while ( my $fh = shift @_ ) {
        close $fh;
    }
}
```

For more compact notation, a `for` loop is the way to go:

```
sub closef { close for @_; }
```

The equivalent with a `while` loop is not so readable:

```
sub closef { close while $_ = shift }
```

#### Update

Michael Carman's comment below holds true here. The `shift` modifies the array being iterated over, which makes it an unsafe operation. This is, in fact, *the* problem.

Comment: There is a problem with the use of `shift`, but it's not the lack of an argument. It will operate on either `@_` or `@ARGV` depending on where it is used; it works on `@_` here. The problem is using it inside a `foreach`. From perlsyn: *`foreach` will get very confused if you add or remove elements within the loop body*.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can also use map:

```
map { close $_ } @_;
```

With map you can even get an array of all results of close calls if you want to process it.

```
my @results = map { close $_ } @_;
```